# How to read a text file into GNU R with a multiple-byte separator?

Tags: r, csv

I can use read.csv or read.csv2 to read data into R. But the issue I encountered is that my separator is a multiple-byte string instead of a single character. How can I deal with this?

Comment: What is your multiple-byte string?

Comment: I believe that if you look at the more general read.table() and the sep argument, you can use a multiple-byte string.

Comment: @mweylandt I think `read.table()`'s `sep` only accepts single bytes (same for `scan()`).

Comment: @jthetzel, oops: sorry about that. I like your solution below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Providing example data would help.  However, you might be able to adapt the following to your needs.

I created an example data file, which is a just a text file containing the following:

```
1sep2sep3
1sep2sep3
1sep2sep3
1sep2sep3
1sep2sep3
1sep2sep3
1sep2sep3
```

I saved it as 'test.csv'.  The separation character is the 'sep' string. I think `read.csv()` uses `scan()`, which only accepts a single character for `sep`.  To get around it, consider the following:

```
dat <- readLines('test.csv')
dat <- gsub("sep", " ", dat)
dat <- textConnection(dat)
dat <- read.table(dat)
```

`readLines()` just reads the lines in. `gsub` substitutes the multi-character seperation string for a single `' '`, or whatever is convenient for your data.  Then `textConnection()` and `read.data()` reads everything back in conveniently.  For smaller datasets, this should be fine. If you have very large data, consider preprocessing with something like AWK to substitute the multi-character separation string.  The above is from http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e4/help/08/04/9296.html .

***Update***
Regarding your comment, if you have spaces in your data, use a different replacement separator. Consider changing `test.csv` to :

```
1sep2 2sep3
1sep2 2sep3
1sep2 2sep3
1sep2 2sep3
1sep2 2sep3
1sep2 2sep3
1sep2 2sep3
```

Then, with the following function:

```
readMulti <- function(x, sep, replace, as.is = T)
{
    dat <- readLines(x)
    dat <- gsub(sep, replace, dat)
    dat <- textConnection(dat)
    dat <- read.table(dat, sep = replace, as.is = as.is)

    return(dat)
}
```

Try:

```
readMulti('test.csv', sep = "sep", replace = "\t", as.is = T)
```

Here, you replace the original separator with tabs (`\t`). The `as.is` is passed to `read.table()` to prevent strings being read in is factors, but that's your call. If you have more complicated white space within your data, you might find the `quote` argument in `read.table()` helpful, or pre-process with AWK, perl, etc.

Something similar with crippledlambda's `strsplit()` is most likely equivalent for moderately sized data. If performance becomes an issue, try both and see which works for you.

Comment: read.table will get the same error message.jthetzel's suggestion sounds like good.Actually I already leverage awk to process the raw data before I read it in R. But the question here is how we can deal with the character in the new separation character after gsub(Say, we DO have a ' ' within the value in your sample code).

Comment: @RobinMin Try a different replacement separator per update above.

Answer (score 4):

In this case you can replace `textConnection(txt)` with your file name, but essentially you can build a code or function around `strsplit`. Here I'm assuming you have a header line, but you can of course give define a `header` argument and generalize the creation of your data frame based on the function below:

```
read.multisep <- function(File,sep) {
    Lines <- readLines(File)
    Matrix <- do.call(rbind,strsplit(Lines, sep, fixed = TRUE))
    DataFrame <- structure(data.frame(Matrix[-1,]), names=Matrix[1,]) ## assuming header is present
    DataFrame[] <- lapply(DataFrame, type.convert)                    ## automatically convert modes
    DataFrame
}

example <- "a#*&b#*&c
            1#*&2#*&3
            4#*&5#*&6"

read.multisep(textConnection(example),sep="#*&")

  a b c
1 1 2 3
2 4 5 6
```