# reading txt with non-binary separators r

Tags: r, separator

I have a problem reading separators in txt file with non-conventional separator "|||".

The problem looks like following:

2|||4|||3|||1|||5|||7

2|||4|||3|||1|||5|||7

Way to replicate it:

```
B = as.data.frame(matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), nrow=2, ncol=3))
B$OUT <- paste0(c(B$V1, B$V2, B$V3), collapse = "|||")
B <- as.data.frame(B$OUT)
```

What is the best way for a heavy txt file (millions of rows) to read it into a proper data.frame?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883859/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-gnu-r-with-a-multiple-byte-separator might be helpful.