# Import text file in r with more than one byte as separator

Tags: r

I have a text file as my data. The text file is delimited using double pipes – i.e. “||”.

The data files look like this:

Cat1||Cat2||Cat3\n
1||abc||23.5

When I load the data with read.table with sep = "||", I get one byte limitation error.

> df <- read.table("data.txt", 
>   +                  header = FALSE,
>   +                  sep = "||")
>   Error in scan(file, what = "", sep = sep, quote = quote, nlines = 1, quiet = TRUE,  : 
>     invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte

In python, I can use '\|\|' as a separator to load the data.
Please help, how can I load the text file data in r data frame?

Comment: There are some functions made in this post which can be useful to read multibyte separators. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883859/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-gnu-r-with-a-multiple-byte-separator

Comment: @RonakShah I followed the link but I am getting below error:-

dat <- readLines("data.txt")
dat <- gsub("||", "~", dat)
dat <- textConnection(dat)
dat <- read.table(dat)

Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
line 5 did not have 2 elements